# How I do convert from timestamp to date in python?

Tags: python, date, datetime

I have this string `'2015-04-08T07:52:00Z'` and I wanna to convert it to `'08/04/2015'`, how can I do this?

Comment: [Date and Time Representation in Python](http://www.seehuhn.de/pages/pdate)

Comment: related: [How to parse ISO formatted date in python?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/127803/4279)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use the `datetime.datetime.strptime()` function to create a datetime object, then `datetime.datetime.strftime()` to return your correctly formatted date like so:

```
from datetime import datetime
dt = datetime.strptime('2015-04-08T07:52:00Z', '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%SZ')
print dt.strftime('%d/%m/%Y')
```

Comment: That means clicking the check mark below the upside-down triangle on the left.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [easy_date](https://github.com/ralphavalon/easy_date) to make it easy:

```
import date_converter
converted_date = date_converter.string_to_string('2015-04-08T07:52:00Z', '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%SZ', '%d/%m/%Y')
```

Comment: you should probably use  a single namespace e.g., `easy_date.string_to_string` (create a package and import the corresponding names, see how [`asyncio`](https://hg.python.org/cpython/file/9dfda4e7169a/Lib/asyncio/__init__.py) or `numpy` do it).